# Linked list implementation - follow-up

Tags: java, object-oriented, linked-list, iterator

Follow-up to this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98551/oop-paradigm-implementation-of-a-linked-list) as recommended.

Can this code be improved from an OOP paradigm perspective?

```
package JavaCollections;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


/**
 * Dlist using sentinel node
 * 
 * @author mohet01
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
public class DblyLinkList<T> implements Iterable<T>{

    /**
     * DListNode is a node in a DblyLinkList
     * 
     * @author mohet01
     *
     */
    private class DListNode<T> {

        /**
         * item references the item stored in the current node. prev references the
         * previous node in the DList. next references the next node in the DList.
         *
         * 
         */

        T item;
        DListNode<T> prev;
        DListNode<T> next;

        /**
         * DListNode() constructor.
         */
        DListNode() {
            this(null);
        }

        DListNode(T item) {
            this.item = item;
            this.prev = null;
            this.next = null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return super.equals(obj);
        }


    }


    private class Itr implements Iterator<T>{

        private int  currentPosition = 0; 

        private int  lastRet = -1;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return currentPosition != size();
        }

        @Override
        public T next() throws NoSuchElementException {
            if (currentPosition > size()){
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            T next = get(currentPosition);
            lastRet = currentPosition;
            currentPosition++;
            return next; 
        } 

        @Override
        public void remove() throws NoSuchElementException{
            if(lastRet < 0 ){
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }else{
                DblyLinkList.this.remove(currentPosition);
                lastRet = -1;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * head references the sentinel node.
     *
     * Being sentinel as part of implementation detail, will avoid null checks,
     * while performing mutable operations on list.
     * 
     * DO NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING FIELD DECLARATIONS.
     * 
     */
    private DListNode<T> head;
    private int size;



    /*
     * 
     * 
     * DblyLinkList invariants: 
     * 1) head != null. 
     * 2) For any DListNode x in a DblyLinkList, x.next != null. 
     * 3) For any DListNode x in a DblyLinkList, x.prev != null. 
     * 4) For any DListNode x in a DblyLinkList, if x.next == y, then y.prev == x.
     * 5) For any DListNode x in a DblyLinkList, if x.prev == y, then y.next == x.
     * 6) size is the number of DListNode's, NOT COUNTING the sentinel (referenced
     * by "head"), that can be accessed from the sentinel by a sequence of "next" references.
     */


    /**
     * DblyLinkList() constructor for an empty DblyLinkList.
     */
    public DblyLinkList() {
        this.head = new DListNode<T>();
        this.head.next = this.head;
        this.head.prev = this.head;
    }

    /**
     * DblyLinkList() constructor for a one-node DblyLinkList.
     */
    public DblyLinkList(T item) {
        this.head = new DListNode<T>();
        this.insertFront(item);
    }

    /**
     * Return the size of the linked list
     * @return
     */
    public int size(){
        return size;
    }

    void remove(int index) throws NoSuchElementException{
        if(index > size()){
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        DListNode<T> node;
        for (node = head; index-- > 0; node = node.next);
        node.item = null;
        node.prev.next = node.next;
        node.next.prev = node.prev;
    }


    /**
     * Inserts a non-sentinel node at front of the list.
     *  
     * @param item
     */

    public void insertFront(T item){

        DListNode<T> node = new DListNode<>(item);
        node.next = head.next;
        node.prev = head;
        node.next.prev = node;
        head.next = node;
        this.size++;
    }

    /**
     * Remove first non-sentinel node from the list.
     * Do not require size check before remove operation
     * 
     */
    public void removeFront(){
        head.next.next.prev = head;
        head.next = head.next.next;
        if(this.size() > 0){
            this.size--;
        }
    }

    public T get(int index) throws NoSuchElementException{
        if (index > size()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        DListNode<T> node;
        for (node = head; index-- > 0; node = node.next);
        return node.item;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new Itr();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Bug

In the `DblyLinkList(T)` constructor, `this.head = new DListNode<T>();` sets up a sentinel node with dangling, rather than self-referencing, `next` and `prev` pointers.  Rather, you should take advantage of your default constructor:

```
public DblyLinkList(T item) {
    this();
    this.insertFront(item);
}
```

### Poor performance scaling

Your iterator's `next()` calls `get(currentPosition)`, and `remove()` calls `remove(currentPosition)`, both of which work by traversing nodes starting from the `head`.  These methods are going to get slower and slower as you move towards the tail of the list.  They should both be O(1).

### Error handling

`removeFront()` quietly does nothing if the list is already empty, in contrast to `get(index)`, which throws `NoSuchElementException`.

### Pointless overriding

`DListNode` has an `equals()` method that just calls `super.equals(obj)`.  You can just remove that code and inherit `equals()` from the superclass.

Comment: I have made the changes [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Java_programming/blob/master/JavaCode/src/JavaCollections/DblyLinkList.java) just for reference.

Comment: Is encapulation taken care in this code?

Comment: `DblyLinkList.remove()` should probably be `public`. Other than that, it looks OK.

Comment: Can you please answer this linked [question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/291455/how-encapsulation-is-different-from-data-abstraction-in-this-java-class)?

Answer (score 1):

Only one thing to point out...

```
/**
 * head references the sentinel node.
 *
 * Being sentinel as part of implementation detail, will avoid null checks,
 * while performing mutable operations on list.
 * 
 * DO NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING FIELD DECLARATIONS.
 * 
 */
private DListNode<T> head;
private int size;
```

This comment *sounds* scary, which is why it's probably an indication of a potential weakness in your implementation. [Comments lie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ), especially when they get outdated, or copied-and-pasted wrongly to other parts of your code. If I want to be even more particular, you are using the plural form here (head reference**s** and field declaration**s**), so are you really referring to both `head` and `size` fields? What happens when someone changes them? If the code is improved upon, when can someone remove the comments?

Comment: comments refer about `head`

Answer (score 0):

As far as OOP paradigm is to be considered, I do not see any problem with the implementation and as per my knowledge and experience of OOP, I can not find any mistake or make any suggestion for any improvement. Well, here are few pointers that I will consider if I will implement the same thing:

1. Naming Convention: `DblyLinkList`, `DNode` doesn't make sense to me. If I were you, I will be making them more readable e.g. `DoublyLinkList` etc.. But this is just my opinion.
2. Your default constructor `DListNode()`, you don't need to do `this(null)` as `T item`, `prev` and `next` are object members so these will be auto initialized as `null`, so I don't see any good reason to do `this(null)`.

Well, these are just few things as per my humble opinion.

Comment: Please read this [comment](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98551/oop-paradigm-implementation-of-a-linked-list?lq=1#comment180717_98556)

Comment: In an empty list, the sentinel's `next` and `prev` pointers need to refer to itself. You can't leave them uninitialized to `null`.